# C# Generics - How do I return a specific type?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong.

I have a bunch of classes that derive from the "Model" class, a base class with a bunch of common properties and methods.  I want them all to implement a set of functionality:

```
public abstract void Create();
public abstract T Read<T>(Guid ID);  //<--Focus on this one
public abstract void Update();
public abstract void Delete();
```

Then I implement it in a child class like "Appointment" like so:

```
public override T Read<T>(Guid ID)
{
  var appt = db.Appointments.First(a => a.AppointmentID.Equals(ID));
  var appointment = new Appointment()
  {
    DateEnd = appt.dateEnd.GetValueOrDefault(),
    Location = appt.location,
    Summary = appt.summary
  };
return appointment;
}
```

This throws an exception "Can't implicitly convert type 'Appointment' to T".  If I change the method's signature to "public override Appointment Read(Guid ID)", then the compiler says that I've not implemented the abstract method in the child class.

What am I missing?  Can anyone give me some code samples?

Comment: What is the motivation behind having your Read method generic ?

Comment: +1 I like the question as I was trying to do something similar. Then realized I was doing it wrong - ended up with a solution very similar to Greg's. If this question had been here 4 days ago, I wouldn't have spent as much time trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: What is the point of using generics if you are not using `T` in your method at all and your want to return an `Appointment`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you could use a generic base class!  Consider something like the following:

```
class Model<T>
{
    public abstract T Read(Guid ID);
}

class Appointment : Model<Appointment>
{
    public override Appointment Read(Guid ID) { }
}
```

Now your subclasses are all strongly typed.  Of course, the tradeoff is that you no longer have a single base class.  A `Model<Appointment>` isn't the same thing as a `Model<Customer>`.  I have not generally found this to be a problem, though, because there's little common functionality-- the interfaces are similar, but they all work with different types.

If you'd like a common base, you can certainly cheat and implement an `object`-based interface that does the same general tasks.  E.g., something in the spirit of (untested, but the idea's there):

```
interface IModelEntity
{
    object Read(Guid ID);
}

class Model<T> : IModelEntity
{
    public T Read(Guid ID)
    {
        return this.OnRead(ID); // Call the abstract read implementation
    }

    object IModelEntity.Read(Guid ID)
    {
        return this.OnRead(ID); // Call the abstract read implementation
    }

    protected abstract virtual T OnRead(Guid ID);
}

class Appointment : Model<Appointment>
{
    protected override Appointment OnRead(Guid ID) { /* Do Read Stuff */ }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to box and cast. I wonder though why this method is generic?

```
return (T)(object)appointment;
```

Comment: Do you think its reasonable to treat maybe 1 object type slightly differently then others, but keep them in the same generic function because you don't want to create more functions then in theory needed?

Answer (score 5):

Would this work?

```
public abstract T Read<T>(Guid ID) where T : IAppointment;
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. You're reasoning about the constraint in the wrong direction; the type parameter constraint constrains the *type argument*. Suppose there were two classes, Appointment and Frob, both of which implement IAppointment. Read<Frob> would be legal because Frob implements IAppointment. But you cannot convert an object of type Appointment to Frob just because they both implement IAppointment!

Answer (score 3):

You must cast to `object` first then to `T`. The reason is rooted in that `object` is at the top of the inheritance chain. There is no direct correlation from `Appointment` to `T`; therefore you have to backtrack to `object`, then find your way back to `T`.

I provided this answer to give an explanation of why the return statement would not work unless it was doubly cast -- and in support of the answers given by Chaos & Greg

Answer (score 2):

**First**, I'd suggest you turn your base class into an interface. If that's an option for you, this will also reduce in slightly less-cluttered code, as you can get rid of the `abstract` and `public` keywords in the interface declaration and omit the `override` in the implementing classes.

**Second**, as your implementation of `Appointment.Read` suggests, you could change the method signature of `Read` to return a model object.

Both suggested changes would result in the following:

```
public interface IModel
{
    void Create();
    IModel Read(Guid ID);
    void Update();
    void Delete();
}
```

**Third**, it seems to me that `Read` should really be a factory method. In your current code, you need to first instantiate an `Appointment` object before you can call the `Read` method to retrieve another `Appointment` object. This seems wrong to me, from a class design perspective.

How about taking `Read` out of the base class/interface and providing it as a static method in all derived/implementing classes? For example:

```
public class Appointment : IModel
{
    public static Appointment Read(Guid ID)
    {
        return new Appointment()
               {
                   ...
               };
    }
}
```

You could also consider moving `Read` into a static (factory) class; however, it would then have to be smart enough to know what kind of object it should return. This would work e.g. if you had a table in your DB that would map a GUID to the corresponding object type.

***Edit**: The last suggestion above used to be this:*

*Third, if this is correct so far, the next question would be whether or not `Read` should be a static method instead. If so, it could be made `static` and be moved into a static `Model` class. The method would then act like a factory method that builds `IModel` objects from a DB:*

```
Guid guid = ...;
IModel someModel = Model.Read(guid);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something funky about this design.

Regardless of whether or not the `Model` class is templated, putting a template parameter on the `Read` method doesn't make a lot of sense as an instance method.

Usually you'd have something like what Greg D posted.

Answer (score 1):

If `public abstract T Read<T>(Guid ID);` of `Model` will only ever return derived types of `Model`, consider changing the signature to

```
public abstract class Model
{
    public abstract void Create();
    public abstract Model Read(Guid ID);  //<--here
    public abstract void Update();
    public abstract void Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your Appointment class add this

```
public class Appointment<T> : Model where T : Appointment
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also call:
`var x = myModel.Read<Appointment>();`