# C# Generics and types

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic method something like:

```
public abstract T method<T>(int arg) where T : class, new();
```

Then I implement it in the child class

```
public MyType method<MyType>(int arg){
    MyType e = new MyType();

    e.doStuff (arg); // ERROR HERE

    return s;
}
```

But I can't access MyType's members... How come ? Is there something I can add to enable them or something ?

Thank you

Miloud

Comment: To acces the Type's member, you have to have a constraint on a base class, interface or use reflection.

Comment: @Miloud - the `<code>` tags don't work when writing your question - I've edited it for you to sort it out. You just need to indent your code with 4 spaces, or highlight it and press the Code (0101) button.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing an `override` there?

Comment: moi_meme thanks I got your point. Clark thanks for the formatting ;) and Marc Gravel I'm missing an override indeed (wrong copy/paste) hehe

Comment: oupse it's supposed to be return e; misspell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this (note that I have moved some of your generic parameters and constraints around).

```
public class MyType
{
    public void doStuff(int i){}
}
public abstract class ABase<T>where T : class, new()
{
    public abstract T method(int arg);
}

public class AChild : ABase<MyType>
{
    override public MyType method(int arg)
    {
        MyType e = new MyType();

        e.doStuff(arg); // no more error here

        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be a very effective technique.  I've also demonstrated it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246587/c-generics-how-do-i-return-a-specific-type/2246610#2246610

Comment: Thanks Albin, I've thought about it that way earlier but actually it turns my code into a freaking ugly old lady's face hehe

Comment: @Miloud B, you other option is to create an interface with the doStuff method and add that to the method constraint `where T : IMyInterface, new();`

Comment: Albin your code above is what I needed, I've just read it wrongly at the beginning, thank you very much !

Comment: @Albin Are you sure its called override public and not public override?

Comment: @Pascal, Both are valid according to http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf (page 286), but you are right in that `public override` is most widely used.

Answer (score 3):

C# does not have template specialization. You nave simply declared a new method with the type-parameter named `MyType`, which has **nothing** to do with the *class* named `MyType`.

You can *cast*, or there are generic constraints you use to declare that `T` is *at least* a `MyType`.

Another option would be to make the base-type *itself* generic in `T` (and remove the generic from the method), and have the concrete type `: TheBaseType<MyType>`

Comment: Wait, I'm interested in the *cast* option, but it comes to the same thing, if I cast to MyType it's still members free.. How do you cast it yourself ?

Comment: @Miloud - I can't really clarify more without understanding the scenario; what is `s`? what is `MyType`? what is the relationship between `T` and `MyType`? For example a type constraint *might* be the way to do this, but I'm not sure if the concrete implementation should be creating `T` or `MyType`, etc

Comment: If you leave the name of the generic type in your method `MyType` and you cast to `MyType`, you're casting to the generic type, not the actual `MyType` type.  Rename your generic parameter for the method to something else (e.g., `T`) and then cast the instance of `T` to `MyType`.

Comment: I got your point Marc and actually what I'm trying to achieve is impossible, I've used different names for Type and Generic but it doesn't change anything, and as you said even if I do cast to MyType it remains a generic type so no way to access its attributes. I think I'm gonna restart my code from scratch and think it differently, thank you for ya help :)

Comment: @Miloud - see Greg's point above; the generic argument should really be `T`; then there *is* the difference between `T` and `MyType`